# How to serve audio files in sping boot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

I have audio tag in html, I need to know the src attribute, where should I put the audio folder to be able to reference it as src="audio/audio_name" ?

I tried to put it in resources folder, but when put src="http://localhost:9191/resources/audios/audio_name" it returned 404 not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to put your audio file into of the following directories:

- `/META-INF/resources/`
- `/resources/`
- `/static/`
- `/public/`

You can then reference a file `/static/audio/file.mp3` from HTML with `/audio/file.mp3`.

See [Serving Static Web Content with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot).

Comment: Thanks, when I put it in static folder, it works, but I didn't find /public/ or /META-INF/ folders in my project structure, is that because I'm on the last version in spring boot? also folder /static/ is inside /resources/

Comment: Base path for the aforementioned directories is always `src/main/resources`, and none of the listed directories exist when you create an empty project. You have to create them.